# Can not map array inside json in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, mapping

I have a simple json with nested array:
`{"pageIndex":1,"items":[{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"}],"hasPage":false}`

I try to map items for the table rendering:

```
import React from 'react'

const TableBody = props => {
    const rows = props.characterData.map((row, index) => {
        return (
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{row.id}</td>
                <td>{row.name}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    })

    return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
}

const Table = props => {
    const { characterData } = props

    return (
        <table>
            <TableBody characterData={characterData} />
        </table>
    )
}

export default Table
```

with

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Table from './Table'

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        characters: [],
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url =
      'http://mysitename.com/api/characters'

    fetch(url)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({
          characters: result,
        })
      })
  }

    render() {
        const { characters } = this.state

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <Table characterData={characters} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App
```

But I give an error: `TypeError: props.characterData.map is not a function`, this code works only for not nested array in json.

When I change to this: `const rows = props.characterData.items.map((row, index) => {` I have an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`
I see in react console that `characterData.items` in `TableBody` have values. But why I can not map them? And why items are undefined?

Comment: I haven't tried but it's probably because you're rendering the table before getting data from the fetch api

Comment: `{characters.length > 0 ? <Table characterData={characters} /> : null}` maybe this will help

Comment: Should be mapping over items inside of characterData instead of characterData itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the shape of the data you're receiving is an object with an `items` array:

```
{
    "pageIndex": 1,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "name1"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "name2"
        }
    ],
    "hasPage": false
}
```

...but your initial state is just an aray:

```
state = {
    characters: []
}
```

So what works with the initial state won't work with what you're saving later.

If all you want from the ajax response is the `items`, you can fix it by keeping your initial state the way it is and changing what you do with the response:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(result => result.json())
  .then(result => {
    this.setState({
      characters: result.items,
//                      ^^^^^^
    });
  });
```

(Then continue to use `props.characterData.map` directly.)

---

Alternatively, you could go the other way:

- Keep the full ajax result
- Make your initial state something like:

  ```js
  state = {
      characters: {
          items: []
      }
  }
  ```
- Use `.items` when passing the data to `Table`.

---

There are two unrelated additional issues to fix:

1. You're not handling errors from `fetch`, and
2. You're not handling the fact that `fetch` only raises an error on *network* error, not on HTTP error; you need to check for HTTP success explicitly

So:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(result => {
      if (!result.ok) {                                    // 
          throw new Error("HTTP error " + result.status);  // Check for HTTP success
      }                                                    // 
      return result.json();
  })
  .then(result => {
    this.setState({
      characters: result.items,
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {                                        //
    // ...handle/report the error...                       // Handle/report errors (network or HTTP)
  });                                                      //
```